# How to integrate merit gem in rails application with devise with different model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have created a rails application, In my rails application I have two models created using devise gem, Student and Teacher. Now I want to add merit gem for Student to assign them badges and points.
    I have tried a lot and follow each and every step given on [1]: https://github.com/tute/merit and also search questions given on stackoverflow, but it's not so much helpful.

In my controller, students/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Students::RegistrationsController <  Devise::RegistrationsController

    def create 
       @student = build_resource
       super
    end
end
```

In my model i have added has_merit in class Student

In my config/initializer/merit.rb

```
Merit.setup do |config|
   config.checks_on_each_request = true
   config.orm = :active_record
   config.user_model_name = 'Student'
end

badge_id = 0
[{
  id: (badge_id = badge_id+1),
  name: 'just-registered'
}, {
  id: (badge_id = badge_id+1),
  name: 'best-unicorn',
  custom_fields: { category: 'fantasy' }
}].each do |attrs|
  Merit::Badge.create! attrs
end
```

My models/merit/badges_rule.rb has the following code line
    grant_on 'students/registrations#create', badge: 'best-unicorn', model_name: 'Student'

i have created all migrations and database tabels.
Everytime on signup my  sash_id set to nil. I don't get the sash_id in Student's table.

Answer (score 1):

What if you only write `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`?

And then in your badges_rule.rb `grant_on 'registrations#create', badge: 'best-unicorn', to: :user`